# Laptop reboots with no reason

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, keyboard, reboot

Here I have Acer 5750G laptop with core i7-2670QM upgraded CPU for three years

~Two weaks ago I had first instant reboot. Now laptop can work 15 minutes or 15 hours as well with very different load (like games, or simple Firefox with music). It reboots with no BSOD/Minidumps (Sure, they're turned on in PC Settings). In event viewer are only Critical Error Kernel Power "System had unexpectly shut down". Airflow is normal, no debris, cleaned up weak ago (with full clean of holes and fan) and there are normal temperatures both CPU and GPU. Reboot is like this: instant shutdown, 3-4 seconds without any activity, power up.
All drivers are up-to-date, no new Software/Hardware were installed 2 weeks ago.
Interesting thing, that with some delay before restart if focus is on text edit field, in this field appear symbols like "0x,.klop-". I have "< ," key broken, but I can press it. Now trying to repeat error with special press broken key. But nothing. It reboots still randomly, but maybe when I press it, don't know now.

So, question: can keyboard cause this "hard" restart? I see that these letters above are in same region of keyboard. Should I buy new keyboard?

Memtest86+ tests passed, sfc and chkdsk both drives are OK. Using Win 8.1 x64 Pro, Antivirus: AVG.

Comment: Verify the heatsink is properly seated.  The fact you a week ago, cleaned it out, is suspect that now you have this problem.

Comment: So before it reboots itself, it types "0x...." if you're in a text field? That looks like it could be a memory address unless it's actually "0x,.klop-". I would suggest using MSE or MBAM to scan, it could be a virus. Or perhaps there's a hardware problem. Are you monitoring CPU temps? It could be overheating.

Comment: @Ramhound I cleaned up PC a weak ago, problem apeeared 2 weaks ago

Comment: You need to go through your question and clarify each of your statements.  Your question is very hard to understand.

Comment: @MC10 I said in message, that temps within normals. Simple example: Firefox, 5 minutes up-time, temp 45, 48, 42, 43, GPU 41 Celsius. Guys, heatsink is on proper place. I used AVG and CureIt to scan. No viruses here

Comment: You are being REALLY dismissive of our suggestions.  There must be reason your computer is shutting itself off, don't be dismissive of our suggestions.

Comment: There no overheating. There are no viruses. Any other ideas?

Comment: I would suggest MBAM but if you're sure there are no viruses and overheating, then it sounds like a hardware problem. Try using it with and without the battery. Have you tried reseating the battery?

Comment: Will try MBAM. Now testing under Linux. I reseated battery only weak ago, when were cleaning laptop. Now will try this too. Thx

Comment: @MC10 upd: MBAM found 0 "bad" files. Simply now I pressed "," in text field appeared ,kliom and then in 5 second display turned off, HDD LED not blinking and laptop not answered any way (keyboard or mouse)

Comment: Tested on linux - simply press and hold comma button. After 1 minute hold - screen flashed 1 time. I repeat hold press button and screen turned down, hdd led not blinking, no answer from OS. Like on Windows. Is it keyboard problem or what?

Comment: It's the nvidia gpu. What driver are you running?

Answer (score 0):

I would try and run it off the battery till its completely drained, reseed the battery and see how you go.

For a test I would try taking the battery out and just running off mains and see if the issue persists.